# ML backup and Amazon S3. How?

Tags: amazon-s3, marklogic, object-storage

I would like to put `MLbackup` directory to cloud. Is there any limitations to pushing Full and incremental backups with journal archiving enabled, to S3 compatible Object storage? Is journal archiving supported in S3 compatible cloud storage? What would happen if I put backup with journal archiving enabled to S3 storage? Will it eventually work or I will get errors?
Also, provide documents link to configure ML to point to cloud storage.

Answer (score 1):

You can backup to S3, but if you want to have Journaling enabled, you will need to have them written to a different location. Journal archiving is not supported on S3.

The default location for Journals are in the backup, but when [creating programmatically](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:database-backup) you can specify a different `$journal-archive-path`.

## [Backing Up a Database](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/backup_restore#id_67513)

The directory you specified can be an operating system mounted directory path, it can be an HDFS path, or it can be an S3 path. For details on using HDFS and S3 storage in MarkLogic, see [Disk Storage Considerations](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/disk-storage#) in the [Query Performance and Tuning Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance).

## [S3 and MarkLogic](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/disk-storage#id_48023)

> Storage on S3 has an 'eventual consistency' property, meaning that write operations might not be available immediately for reading, but they will be available at some point. Because of this, **S3 data directories in MarkLogic have a restriction that MarkLogic does not create Journals on S3**. Therefore, MarkLogic recommends that you use S3 only for backups and for read-only forests, otherwise you risk the possibility of data loss. If your forests are read-only, then there is no need to have journals.

Comment: So you mean when we create a schedule backup it is not possible to specify a different location. I mean a different path for Journals is possible programmatically only.

Comment: Correct. You can create a scheduled backup with a custom  path for journals, but would need to create it programmatically. The UI currently does not have options to let you specify a custom journal path.

Comment: Does MarkLogic supports only Amazon S3? Or does it also support any other Object Storage that is S3 compatible ?